# Custom h.264 streams broken in some hardware decoders

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, codec

I've been banging my head against a wall on this one.  I'm working on a mechanism to code data into a valid h.264 stream.  I've gotten it working and it plays back with tools like mplayer, celluloid, and vlc (software, VA-API and VA-API with DRM), and ffmpeg.  ffmpeg can even repackage and all is well.

But, in situations where hardware decoding is used for instance VDPAU, it doesn't work at all.

This also holds true on windows!

This can be seen on this example code here: https://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/worlds-smallest-h-264-encoder

The code I'm working with is a little more sophisticated and only has timestamp warnings in ffmpeg, https://github.com/cnlohr/h264fun/blob/dfa95a6ed0b669fe1e15d67cd3cbd45ac24cc79d/testbase.c

But some of the things I'm worried about is if I_PCM is supported in hardware decoding or what could possibly be triggering issues?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is broken in VDPAU in Linux on my system.  Some other definitely valid H.264 streams aren't playing, and I've tested my application and it runs in all Windows, android, etc. players.